# Django error: unresolved import 'extra_views'

Tags: python, django, django-views

I'm trying to use extra_view Django package. I've installed it and in terminal it showed as successful and I added it to installed apps in setting.py. As I don't use virtual environment it's all installed globally, but when I try to import that package there is an unresolved import error. I use VS Code if it means something. It also happened with some other packages that I installed. Do you have any idea what is happening?

Answer (score 0):

Can you show full traceback to this error?

And your code where you import it.

It should work fine if you do everything as it says here in the docs:
https://django-extra-views.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pages/getting-started.html

Answer (score 0):

Everything is ok actually. I just restarted VS Code and then there weren't any errors anymore. Apparently VS Code was the only issue.